# llenar arreglo de bidemensional a partir de una lista

Tags: java, array, arraylist, array-bidimensional

como puedo llenar un arreglo bidimensional donde en la 1ra dimension tenga nombre y en la 2da su respectiva edad. Estos datos los tengo en un arraylist donde cada objeto de el si tiene ademas carnet.... por lo que no me sirve convertir la lista en un arreglo. Esto en Java.

Comment: Saludos @JoséDavid, por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/592136/edit) tu pregunta y agrega el código que tienes o que intentaste hacer. ;)

Comment: Te recomendaría crear un objeto con esas propiedades y llenar tu lista de instancias de ese objeto. Sea como sea, dinos qué has hecho hasta ahora y qué dificultades tienes con lo logrado por el momento.

Comment: Como menciona @A.Cedano es conveniente que trabajaras con POO, explota las capacidades del lenguaje y no te compliques, si necesitas hacerlo con un arreglo, deberías checar [ArrayList.html#toArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()). O ya en el caso menos recomendable hacerlo con ciclos.

Comment: Y por favor lee el artículo [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido, podrías mostrarnos como están guardados los datos en el ArrayList, y como quieres que quede tu array bidimensional?, si no muestras que has intentado, sería estupendo, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.